# Web Scrape Daily Treasury Rates

Tags: vba, web, web-scraping

I have tried to write some VBA that scrapes a table from the URL below. I would like to create a macro that pulls in the data on a daily basis. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

https://home.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/TextView?type=daily_treasury_yield_curve&field_tdr_date_value_month=202212

I am having problems understanding HTML and the elements function.

Answer (score 1):

I know you want to scrape that table on the treasury page, but it just has daily values of rates for each maturity duration (2yr, 5yr, etc.). These same rates are published every day in their XML feed.

The XML feed is meant to be consumed and parsed by computer code, while the HTML on that page is NOT meant to be parsed by "screen-scrapers".

If your macro pulled in the data from their XML feed every day instead, and you kept a table/log/whatever of each day's rates, after two weeks, you'd have the exact same data as the treasury HTML table, but NOT have all the headaches of trying to parse HTML and always worrying about your code breaking if their HTML layout changes.

Would this later approach work for you?

Update: Eric Salazar's answer reminded me of something. I don't know if you're using Excel VBA, or some other Office app, but if you ARE using Excel, you can use the "'Data Menu'->Get Data->From Other Sources->From Web" feature to import that treasury table into an Excel table. Simply copy the URL of that page, paste it into the URL field of the first dialog that pops up (keep type as "Basic"), click OK, click "Table 0" under Display Options of the next ("Navigator") dialog, and lastly click "Load". By default it will create a table in the current worksheet at the currently selected cell. It will contain all the columns of what's on the treasury page and a few more columns that will be filled with "N/A" (not sure where Excel is getting the N/A field names from). You can get rid of those fields by going into the Power Query Designer before importing the data (instead of clicking "Load" in the previous "Navigator" dialog, click "Transform Data" instead. This will open up the "Power Query Editor" and you'll see a table editor in the main window. Select the column headers you don't want to end up in the table and hit the "Del" key (or right-click and choose "Remove Columns"). The selected columns will now be gone. Now click "Close and Load" in the upper-left corner of the Power Query Editor window.

And like magic, Excel will create a new table on your current worksheet with the data contained on that treasury page. You can then access the table with regular VBA code to refresh and read the values.